# IIS and Apache same domain setup

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, reverse-proxy

I was tasked with setting up IIS running website in .asp and apache running forum in .php on the same Windows machine. The deal is that urls should look like: 
http://www.domain.name/ - IIS and 
http://www.domain.name/forum - apache

Is that kind of setup even possible?

Kindly thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install the php forum application on IIS? This would simplify your setup and simpler is usally better.

If that's not possible then you would have to install both IIS an Apache on the same machine but in different ports and then use one of them as a reverse proxy for the other.